# jquery action on loading page

Tags: jquery

I'm using a script which activates a light-box (popup). the popup decides whether the shopping basket has been filled correctly if it has then i wish it to close onload if not then the user has to click to acknowledged that something is wrong. I've got the click to close script working how could i use this script to close the pop without any action ie. onload or something can you help?

this is what i use to close the window on click

```
<a href='javascript:closePopup(300);'>close window</a>
```

would it be possible to add this to close pop with our action?

```
<body onLoad(closePopup(300))>
```

Comment: It would make more sense to check the state of the shopping basket before opening the popup - it would then not flicker on/off. Can you post the code which is opening the popup and the condition you are checking for.

Comment: You need to re-architect your solution, you should script to check the shopping basket and open the popup if faulty rather than open the popup, check and then close if found to be good. It'll make your life so much easier going forward.

Comment: Please could you name or link to the jQuery plugin you're using for the popup?

Comment: This could be done if i new how jquery could read a response after a ajax call. the basket is written in php it check whether its full or needs a new basket adding. how do you find a response from your ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [window.onbeforeunload](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm) and window.onunload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  window.onbeforeunload = doExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "Your shopping cart is still open. Do you want to leave this page?";
  }
  function doExit() 
  {
    closePopup(300);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with lazarus on the design approach, but if you must do it that way you can use the javascript function below to close a window.

```
window.self.close();


<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){
    alert("Page is loaded");
    window.self.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
```